# Sony Stock Messaging App Problems

Tags: sony, sony-xperia

So with Stock Sony Xperia Messaging App, it is the only app that can utilize T-Mobile's Wi-Fi Calling which allows sending and receiving MMS/group messaging over Wi-Fi. T-Mobile has locked the use of T-Mobile Wi-Fi Calling to only stock messaging apps built into the phone. The stock Xperia Messaging App is all great and all, but it can't/doesn't know how to handle group messaging, which is kind of annoying seeing how the app is very well built. Is there a way to contact the Sony App Developers to see if they can fix this in an over the air update?

Answer (score 0):

This is supposedly fixed in Lollipop:

https://support.t-mobile.com/thread/93372